# SQL Server Data Tools (VS2017) Error with Data Flow Tasks

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, etl, sql-server-data-tools

When adding any kind of data flow task or attempting to edit one on the design surface, I get the error

> "The task with the name ... and the creation name "SSIS.Pipeline.6" is not registered for use on this computer. Contact Information: Data Flow Task"

Additionally, an error similar to the following is displayed for all properties of the data flow task:

> "Could not get value for property '{1A11EC69-3AC7-475A-9E7A-B452B6BA6301}'. Specified cast is not valid."

I have looked in the GAC and there is no component with this CLSID, nor do I see it in the .dtproj file

Oddly enough, the package will run from the designer, but pops up an error message on every data flow task that says:

> "This task does not have a custom editor. Use the Poperties window to edit properties of this task".

As long as I keep clicking it, it will continue through. Makes me think the issue is with SSDT or Integration Services, but I have uninstalled and reinstalled both. The issue with editing or viewing properties for a data flow task, however, persists :(

I have VS2015 on the same system, and it appears unaffected. Any idea how to correct this without a full wipe of VS2017?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b62a4183-d04a-4cd7-91dc-8836c3a292ec/the-task-with-the-name-and-the-creation-name-is-not-registered-for-use-on-this-computer?forum=sqlintegrationservices), do the following steps to solve this:

1. open sql server configuration manager
2. choose sql server services
3. right click sql server integration services, choose properties
4. choose log on tab, select this account, enter your username and password which is used to log on your computer.
5. reopen the visual studio. There you are, the task component can work properly again.

If you are using a custom SSIS component then follow this [Link](http://ho-media.co.uk/blog/ssis-custom-component-is-not-registered-for-use-on-this-computer/)

Comment: Not the issue. I can't open the data flow task in designer, at all (not to edit, view properties, etc.) -> not even if I'm set to work offline.

I just uninstalled and reinstalled Integration Services, as well as SSDT -> no luck. The problem happens even in a blank project just by adding a data flow task.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same issue with Visual Studio 2022 and SQL Server 2022 when working with SSIS packages.  I can't even resolve it with a full wipe of Visual Studio.